# SensorTag bluepy update interval

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I'm using bluepy on my Raspberry PI 3 to collect data from a SensorTag.
No matter what I set as `tag.waitForNotifications(0.1)`, the update interval still remains 1 second.

Can you please point me to the right function or documentation.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be setting update period like this:

```
tag.getCharacteristics(uuid='f000aa83-0451-4000-b000-000000000000')[0].write(struct.pack("B", 0xa))
```

where `f000aa83-0451-4000-b000-000000000000` is the characteristic ([found here](https://github.com/geobio/sensortag/blob/master/BleSensorTag/src/main/java/com/example/ti/ble/sensortag/SensorTagGatt.java#L107)) for the update period of the movement sensor (in tens of milliseconds) and `0xa` is the hex representation of 100ms divided by 10.

here is my complete function:

```
import bluepy
from bluepy import sensortag

import sys
import traceback
import struct    

def connect(mac):
  tag = None

  print('connecting to '+mac, end='', flush=True)
  while tag == None:
    try:
      tag = sensortag.SensorTag(mac)
    except (bluepy.btle.BTLEException):
      print('.', end='', flush=True)
    except (Excpetion, e):
      print()
      print(e)
      sys.exit()

  print()
  tag.gyroscope.enable()
  tag.accelerometer.enable()

  # get MovementSensor period characteristic
  gp = tag.getCharacteristics(uuid='f000aa83-0451-4000-b000-000000000000')
  # set 100ms (100ms/10 = 0xa in hex(10))
  gp[0].write(struct.pack("B", 0xa))

  return tag
```

In this case the update period has about 100ms limitation. There is one more way where you could change the source code of tag's firmware.